# How can I emulate Ubuntu 18.04 on MacOS using qemu?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

How can I run Ubuntu 18.04 on my MacBook Air (Mojave) using QEMU? (yes I have to use QEMU for now.) I got QEMU [from here](https://www.emaculation.com/forum/viewtopic.php?%20f=34&t=8848&sid=231f98d16d73cb47e9f5261555fd021f). But also got it from Homebrew as well.

I've tried looking at the [QEMU's System Emulation User's Guide](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/) but I don't really understand it. I also found a [rather good tutorial which seemed to suit me well](https://graspingtech.com/ubuntu-desktop-18.04-virtual-machine-macos-qemu/) but it doesn't work. I actually managed to get the "Install Ubuntu" up menu on screen a couple times, but then the cursor wouldn't work for some reason. 
I first created a qcow2 file like this:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 ~/Desktop/QEMU/ubuntu.qcow2 25G
```

My qemu.command file is:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -m 2048 \
  -vga virtio \
  -show-cursor \
  -usb \
  -device usb-tablet \
  -enable-kvm \
  -cdrom ~/Desktop/QEMU/ubuntu.iso \
  -drive file=~/Desktop/QEMU/ubuntu.qcow2,if=virtio \
  -accel hvf \
  -cpu host
```

I still don't understand why it worked a couple times, and when it worked, the mouse didn't function.

I reinstalled the iso and created a new .qcow2 file and now every single time I am first greeted with some sort of command prompt followed by a [purple screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLDGb.png), sometimes with the "Language" bar at the top (which I can't seem to interact with) and sometimes without, and then afterward some command stuff I don't understand (and can't copy and paste because the mouse doesn't move so I have [a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fdsy.png)).

If someone could explain what I am doing incorrectly and give me some sort of a simple guide, that would be very helpful :). Thank you!

Comment: So since I asked this question, I no longer have access to the macOS device I used. However, if I ever get my hands on an older MacBook, the first thing I will do is to try to replicate the circumstances I had and see if the answer works.

Answer (score 0):

If you change `-cpu host` to something else, like `-cpu Penryn,kvm=on,vendor=GenuineIntel` you most likely can get it working. Why that's happening I don't know. It could be a similar issue to this one https://github.com/Leoyzen/KVM-Opencore/issues/1 – when using host CPU QEMU doesn't re-create topology properly.